# Define an instance method given a class and an UnboundMethod

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a library which wraps methods with spies (basically transparently allows you to add callbacks to methods). I currently have it working fine for dealing with bound methods

```
class FakeClass
  def self.hello_world
    'hello world'
  end

  def age
    25
  end
end

module Spy
  def self.on(receiver, msg)
    original = receiver.method(msg)
    wrapped = Proc.new {|*args| original.call(*args)}
    original.owner.instance_eval do
      define_method msg, wrapped
    end
  end
end

# works
Spy.on(FakeClass, :hello_world)

# also works
Spy.on(FakeClass.new, :age)

# what I want to do
Spy.on_any_instance(FakeClass, :age)
```

So far I've noticed a couple things:

```
FakeClass.methods.include? :age
# => false
FakeClass.instance_method :age
# => #<UnboundMethod FakeClass#age>
```

Which leads me to my question:

Since `instance_method` returns an UnboundMethod, how can I define a replacement method to override that (e.g. I'd like a `define_instance_method`)

Also how can I wrap the UnboundMethod so that it is bound to the instance when the instance is created?

Can I do any of this without messing with the `initialize` method?

EDIT:

With Ajedi32's advice I was able to change my method to something like this (the API is slightly more complex in my library, but you'll get the gist):

```
def wrap_original
  context = self
  @original.owner.instance_eval do
    define_method context.msg do |*args|
      if context.original.respond_to? :bind
        result = context.original.bind(self).call(*args)
      else
        result = context.original.call(*args)
      end
      context.after_call(result, *args)
      result
    end
  end
end

def unwrap_original
  context = self
  @original.owner.instance_eval do
    define_method context.msg, context.original
  end
end
```

EDIT:

Link to my gem in the wild. This is the main entry point (API) which interacts with Core and then instantiates a new Instance https://github.com/jbodah/spy_rb/blob/a40ed2a67b088bfb7d40d12c5b6ffc882a5097c8/lib/spy/api.rb

Comment: Where you said, "you'll get the gist", you forgot to provide the URL.

Comment: Even with bound methods, your original code may (or may not) get you into trouble: `class Mates; def say() puts "I know the perfect guy for you."; end; end; ;class Guys < Mates; end; class Girls < Mates; end; 
Spy.on(Girls.new, :say); Girls.new.say; Guys.new.say`. SO: why must we accept these formatting limitations in comments?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll throw some more tests around spying post-initialization

Comment: Did some testing. I have two API methods (one spies on `:method`, the other on `:instance_method`). Spying `on_any_instance` seems to work post-initialization. The case Cary mentioned is handled by the normal `:method` flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`define_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Module.html#method-i-define_method) actually *does* define an instance method by default. The only reason it's defining a class method instead in your case is because you're calling it inside of [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval). (For details on the exact behavior of `instance_eval`, you may want to read [this article](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/)). A simpler way to do what you want in that first case is to define a singleton method on the receiver object using [`define_singleton_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method):

```
module Spy
  def self.on(receiver, msg)
    original = receiver.method(msg)

    # Use `define_singleton_method` to define a method directly on the receiver
    receiver.define_singleton_method(msg) do |*args, &block|
      puts "Calling #{msg} with args #{args}" # To verify it's working
      original.call(*args, &block) # Call with &block to preserve block args
    end
  end
end

Spy.on(FakeClass, :hello_world)
FakeClass.hello_world # Prints: Calling hello_world with args []

f = FakeClass.new
Spy.on(f, :age)
f.age # Prints: Calling age with args []
```

As for your `on_any_instance` method, you can use the regular [`define_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Module.html#method-i-define_method) method for that. You will have to call it using [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-send) though, since `define_method` is private. And since the original method you're trying to call is an [`UnboundMethod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind), you'll have to [bind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind) it to the instance you want to call it on before calling it:

```
module Spy
  def self.on_any_instance(receiver, msg)
    original = receiver.instance_method(msg) # Get `UnboundMethod`

    # We must call `define_method` with `send`, since it's private
    receiver.send(:define_method, msg) do |*args, &block|
      puts "Calling #{msg} with args #{args}"

      # Method gets bound to `self`, the current instance
      original.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end

Spy.on_any_instance(FakeClass, :age)
FakeClass.new.age # Prints: Calling age with args []
```

Comment: I guess my real confusion is the value of `self` in different blocks. If I understand this correctly, then `self` inside the scope of `define_method` is the current instance

Comment: @JoshBodah Yes. Normally the value of self doesn't change inside of blocks. However, for certain special methods like `instance_eval` and `define_method`, the value of `self` will be different inside the block than it is outside it. In the case of `define_method`, this is because the contents of the block become the body of the newly created method, and inside methods the value of `self` is the same as the object the method is defined on.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I can do this:

```
original = FakeClass.instance_method(:age)
FakeClass.instance_eval {:define_method, :age, original}
```

But I need to see how I can wrap the method now

Comment: Correct, `define_method` does work on unbound methods.